# My window subset Linux airmon-ng not giving any detail

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I am using kali linux on window 10 by enabling the developers mode and then window subset for linux, I was trying to learn how to use aircrack-ng by following a tutorial,
[Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_MJhf8QFpg)
He uses the following commands
fconfig

```
- airmon-ng check kill
- airmon-ng check
- airmon-ng start wlan0
- airodump-ng wlan0mon
- ctrl +c
- reaver -i wlan0mon -b (Copied Bssid) -vv -K 1
```

but when i type airmon-ng

```
 airmon-ng

PHY     Interface       Driver          Chipset
```

when i type ifconfig

```
ifconfig
eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.199.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.199.255
        inet6 fe80::a04a:69f:439b:fd7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.48.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.48.255
        inet6 fe80::f5d8:155:ee4c:bf82  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0xfd<compat,link,site,host>
        ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 1500
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        loop  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wifi0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::94a4:7d1e:ef3d:7849  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        unspec 28-56-5A-8D-1A-47-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and for iwconfig

```
 iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth2      no wireless extensions.

eth3      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wifi0     no wireless extensions.

wifi1     no wireless extensions.

wifi2     no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please update your post to include the relevant steps of the tutorial that you followed. Could you [add a link to it as well](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/447553/edit)? You also mention "window subset", what does this mean? Do you mean [the Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) If you are having an issue using WSL your question will most likely get better responses on the superuser site.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Actually the command airmon-ng does not give the interface and phy and driver, however it gives it in the tutorial so how to fix it, plus i am using the windows subsystem for linux

Comment: What is the output of `iw list | grep "Supported interface modes" -A12`

Comment: Failed to connect to generic netlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the airmon man page.....

First, the tutorial you are following assumes your wireless interface is `wlan0` but yours is `wifi0` so the correct command is

`airmon-ng start wifi0`

Once you get that done airmon will tell you the monitor interface name it has assigned `wifi0` which will probably be `wifi0mon` not `wlan0mon` so the next command will be

`airodump-ng wifi0mon`

**if** you get that far you will probably find your internal wireless card does not support monitor/injection mode, so before you even start, check your hardware, make sure it is compatible and if not go and buy a USB wireless  that is. A start point for hardware is [here at aircrack](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/~~V/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers)

One other thing. I have not tried what you are doing on the Windows subsystem for Linux (which is actually `Ubuntu`, not `Kali`) but I do use the subsystem occasionally.

My experience is that all sorts of things are not in the right place and its a right royal pain in the butt to use. You would be far better off with a VM running under `Virtualbox` or similar and a Debian or Ubuntu install.

I use Kali daily and am very comfortable with it, but I would **not** recommend it to kick off with. All the Kali tools when learning should run under Ubuntu and you will get better support on Ubuntu. Learn to swim in those shallows **then** come and swim in the deep end.

Comment: but i want to learn hacking so what would i do in shallow, please tell what to do in ubuntu

Comment: @Umer You will waste more and more time without knowing  some linux ,security, network .... basics.

Comment: @Umer **You can install all the Kali tools in Ubuntu**. There is no such magical skill as `hacking` nor are there any tools to teach this. You need to understand about how machines communicate across networks,  the protocols, their weaknesses and how to exploit them. Get an ebook like `initiating to ethical hacking` or `Kali Linux wireless pen testing` read it, try out a few of the things and once you understand what you don't know, THEN you can start learning..... but before you even try THAT then take @GAD3R advice and get some command line skills.